# Do Visualforce expressions work with Datatables.js?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Visualforce page that renders a list of the top ten sales performers in a Datatable.js table (so that it is searchable and sortable, and generally prettier).

```
<apex:page Controller="DataTableExampleController" readOnly="true">

    <head>
        <apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
        <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
        <script>
            j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
            j$(document).ready( function () {
                var top10Table = j$('[id$="top10Table"]').DataTable({
                    "order": []

                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="top10Table" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Amount (USD)</th>
                    <th>Sales Person</th>
                    <th>Owner Region</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!ResultsTopTenSales}" var="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td><apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###, ### .##}"><apex:param value="{!item.AmountX}"/></apex:outputText></td>
                        <!-- Variable for Owner.Region (formula fields cannot be grouped in SOQL) -->
                        <apex:variable var="salesPersonAndRegion" value="{!item.OwnerX}"></apex:variable>
                        <td>{!item.OwnerX}</td>
                        <td><apex:param value="{!TODAY()}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
```

I have a formula field that ideally I would have grouped in my aggregate SOQL in the controller...

```
/* Top Ten Sales, across all Opportunity record types */
lstArTopTenSales = [SELECT SUM(Amount)amt, owner.name oName FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName =: stagesClosedWon AND CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD' GROUP BY owner.name ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC limit 10];}
```

... but due to the [known limitation](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HlNtAAK) that SOQL GROUP BY does not work with formula fields, I was attempting to use a Visualforce CASE expression:

```
        <tbody>
            <apex:repeat value="{!ResultsTopTenSales}" var="item">
                <tr>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###, ### .##}"><apex:param value="{!item.AmountX}"/></apex:outputText></td>
                    <!-- Variable for Owner.Region (formula fields cannot be grouped in SOQL) -->
                    <apex:variable var="salesPersonAndRegion" value="{!item.OwnerX}"></apex:variable>
                    <td>{!item.OwnerX}</td>
                    <td><apex:param value="{!CASE(salesPersonAndRegion, "David Beckham", "United Kingdom", "TBD")}/></td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

This wasn't working, so I assumed something must have been wrong with my VF Case Expression. So I simplified it further to read:

{!item.OwnerX}

but this doesn't work either:

[image]

Can Visualforce expressions be used with Datatables.js? I am unsure why nothing is appearing in the third column, 'Owner Region'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem's with your expression:

```
<td><apex:param value="{!CASE(salesPersonAndRegion, "David Beckham", "United Kingdom", "TBD")}/></td>
```

This is simply creating a page parameter, such as you'd use for an actionFunction. There's no output this way. Simply use the merge field directly:

```
<td>{!CASE(salesPersonAndRegion, "David Beckham", "United Kingdom", "TBD")}</td>
```

Your code, `{!item.OwnerX}`, is actually appearing in the second column, which you've got blanked out, so I'm presuming it works.

Comment: do you know if there is a char limit for a Visualforce expression? I couldn't find anything in the docs to suggest this. I'm just curious around this.

Comment: @AndyHitchings there's no "per-formula" limit that I've ever found, but keep in mind that expressions may cost "view state" size, which is limited to 135k. If you can help it, I suggest calculating values in Apex Code rather than Visualforce.